# my code crashes when introducing giant numbers

Tags: c++

i have the next code which asks the user to introduce a number larger than 100000000, and then it asks for a digit that the code must search in the number, finally the code shows how many times the digit appears on the number, it seems to be easy but i have a restriction:

the data type cannot be a string or a char, thats why i am using an int, but when i introduce a real big number like 100100010000100 the code just doesn´t work properly, how could i solve this, any ideas???if someone could help me out with this i would appreciate it a lot

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int searchDigit(long int num,int digit);

int main()
{
    long int num;
    int digit,x;
        cout << "Give me the number: " << endl;
        cin >> num;
        cout << "Digit " << endl;
        cin >> digito;
        x = searchDigit(num,digit);
        cout << "\nThe digit " << digit << " appears " << x << " times" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int searchDigit(long int num,int digit)
{
    int r,c,p = 0;
    for(c = num;c != 0;c = c/10)
    {
        r = c % 10;
        if(r == digit)
           p++;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Either use `long` or `long long` or use an arbitrary precision library like GMP.

Comment: Why can't the data type be a char or a string

Comment: @uli, even using unsigned long long (0..18,446,744,073,709,551,615) will eventually run out of digits.

Comment: @uncletall That's correct and the reason why I recommended GMP (which is of course slower than `unsigned long long`). The OP didn't ask for any integral range specifically, so what to use really depends on the usecase

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in `searchDigit` you have `c = num` in the for-loop. If `long int` is larger than `int` - which is true on many platforms - you will lose the high bits of `num`.

If you enabled more compiler warnings, this would probably be picked up. It's hard to be more specific, since you haven't provided information about the platform, compiler, or the flags used.